# Ruby on Rails - Forms with belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, belongs-to

On Rails 4. I have three Models (for this question): `Users`, `Organizations`, and `UserOrganizations`. Users can have many organizations, and organizations can have many users. This relationship is stored in UserOrganizations with `user_id` and `organization_id`. So, UserOrganizations belongs to users and organizations.

When I want to add a new user/organization relationship, the `user_id` is automatically taken from the current user logged in. However, to assign that user to an organization, I have a dropdown select, listing all the organizations in the database (by name).

This is fine in the dev environment but not so great when I will eventually have over a thousand organizations.

What I would like to do is have a sort of text look-up input where the user can type in an organization's name and then all orgs in the database containing that name will display. Then the user can select the name (through a radio button maybe?) to tell the app which org he/she would like to be assigned. Ideally, this would happen on the same page/no reload.

What is the best way to create this form? Is there a gem or something else that exists to easily make this? Can you do this with formtastic or even without a gem? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably take a look to [rails3-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) gem. It has quite documentation and examples. More or less:

Model:

```
class UserOrganization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :organization_name
end
```

Controller:

```
class UserOrganizationsController < Admin::BaseController
  autocomplete :organization, :name
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :user_organizations do
  get :autocomplete_organization_name, :on => :collection
end
```

View:

```
form_for(@user_organization) do |f|
  f.hidden_field :organization_id, id: 'org_id'
  f.autocomplete_field :organization_name, autocomplete_organization_name_user_organizations_path, id_element: '#org_id'
end
```

It also provides integration with `SimpleForm` and `Formtastic`.

Comment: Hmm, this is not working for me, even after restarting the server multiple times. First, in the view, (remember I'm finding orgs and I want the search to be by the org's :name) is it :organization_name or just :organization ? Keeping it as :organization_name returned undefined method `organization_name' (I had already changed the route/controller). Changing it to just :organization didn't load an error but the autocomplete isn't there at all. Does this work with Rails 4? What am I doing wrong? Seems straightforward and yet...

Comment: Update: I've decided to use the select2 gem instead. Way easier and I got that working instantly.

Comment: Another good option :), I also use it. I'll edit the answer adding some clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

Make a text_field_tag (For the search).

```
<%= text_field_tag(:for_search, "", :onchange=> "search_orgs(this)") %>
```

On the onchange event of that text_field, put a JS function that runs an AJAX request that sends as a parameter the string you want to search on.

```
<script>
   function search_orgs(theString)
   {
     var dataString = 'string='+theString;
     $.ajax(
     {  
       type: "GET",  
       url: "/your_path/show(or_create)",  
       data: dataString  
     }); 
     return false;
   }
</script>
```

That way, everytime your textfield changes, the string you enter will be send as a parameter to the controller (in this example, the show method).

In your show method, capture the param, use it to filter your data, and then populate the select_tag.

Your Controller

```
def show
  string = params[:string]
  yourFiltered_data = Yourmodel.where("name ILIKE = '#{string}'").all
  yourFiltered_data .each do |d|  
    @htmlSelect+="<option value = #{d.organization_id}>#{d.organization_name}</option>"     
  end
end
```

Now, in a show.js.erb file in your view folder, you put this

show.js.erb file

```
$(document.getElementById("theOrgs").innerHTML = '<%= select_tag :organization_id, @htmlSelect.html_safe %>')
```

That way, everytime your textbox value changes, the select_tag options will also change and will only feature those companies that contain the string your submitted in their names.

Hope this helps!